# Why isn't there a find_or_create_by! method with mongoid?

Tags: mongoid

Mongoid offers methods `create` and `create!`
such as

```
Artist.create(name: "Pablo Picasso")
```

or

```
Artist.create!(name: "Pablo Picasso")
```

Mongoid also offers a convenient method called `find_or_create_by`
such as

```
a = Artist.find_or_create_by(name: "Pablo Picasso")
```

It seems Mongoid should supply a method `find_or_create_by!`
to raise an exception if validation fails and it can't create the document.

I know with Mongoid 3.1.0, you can do

```
Artist.where(name: "Pablo Picasso").first_or_create
```

or

```
Artist.where(name: "Pablo Picasso").first_or_create!
```

But aren't they equivalent to `find_or_create_by` and `find_or_create_by!` (if one exists?)?

The `find_or_create_by` syntax is much shorter hence nicer...

Comment: just info [find_or_create_by!](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/Mongoid/Criteria/Modifiable#find_or_create_by!-instance_method) in mongoid

Answer (score 1):

You`re right, right now there is no find_or_create_by! method. Please open a new issue https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/issues/new and I will add that as soon as I have time.

Thanks for asking anyways.